# Variants of Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am planing to buy Samsung Galaxy S5 phone. However, I am confused between the variants of this phone. The following [versions](http://www.payless.pk/index.php?route=product/search&search=g900) are available in my country but when I click on each of the variants, the site doesn't specify any difference between the versions.

1. Samsung Galaxy S5 3G G900H
2. Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900H
3. Samsung Galaxy S5 4G LTE G900F

What are the differences between these variants? Especially between

- 1 & 2
- 2 & 3

Answer (score 6):

The 3G G900H and the SM-G900H are the same, but SM-G900H is the proper name for it.

Now that we know those two devices are the same, we can compare the SM-G900H with the G900F-

**SM-G900H**

Only supports 3G HSPA+ networks, no LTE support, and will work nearly everywhere in the world except some markets in north/south america

Uses an Exynos 5 Octa 5422 processor (Split into a quad-core 1.9 GHz Cortex-A15, and a quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A7)

Does not have a good development community for custom recoveries/ROMs

**SM-G900F**

European model

Supports LTE networks (bands 1,3,5,7,8,20)

Uses a Snapdragon 801 (quad core 2.5 GHz)

Has a fairly good development community (custom recoveries/ROMs/etc)

**Benchmark**

[image: Exynos 5422 vs Snapdragon 801]

**Misc**

SM-G900H has a 133 MHz higher stock RAM speed than the SM-g900f, supports hardware assisted virtualization, and is generally more power efficient.

Comment: I just looked up US T-Mobile LTE band and it is stated to be 4. Does it mean none of these models will have LTE on US T-Mobile network?

Answer (score 2):

Pacnet presented the main differences, here is a [detailed comparison](http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/comparison/78e31663):

[image]

[Some local variants](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2711487&page=5):

```
Samsung SM-G900F for Europe
Samsung SM-G900I for Asia
Samsung SM-G900K/G900L/G900S for Korea
Samsung SM-G900M for Vodafone
Samsung SM-G900A for AT&T
Samsung SM-G900T for T-Mobile

3G Network  HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100 - SM-G900F
HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 - SM-G900M
HSDPA 850 / 1900 / 2100 - SM-G900A
HSDPA 850 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 - SM-G900T
4G Network  LTE 800 / 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 / 2100 / 2600 - SM-G900F
LTE 700 / 850 / 1700 / 1900 / 2100 / 2600 - SM-G900M
LTE 700 / 850 / 1700 / 1800 / 1900 / 2100 / 2600 - SM-G900A
LTE 700 / 850 / 900 / 1700 / 1800 / 1900 / 2100 / 2600 - SM-G900T

all of those variant have same hardware (SM-G900F).
```

A longer list:

```
Galaxy S5 SM-G900F - LTE 800/850/900/1800/1900/2100/2600 Europe(LTE Variants) for Europe 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900HNO - Europe(3G Variants octa-core) 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900I - LTE 700/850/900/1800/1900/2100/2300/2600 Asia
Galaxy S5 SM-G900K - LTE 700/900/1800/2100/2600 Korea
Galaxy S5 SM-G900L - LTE 600/850/1800/2100 Korea
Galaxy S5 SM-G900S - LTE 600/850/1800/2100 Korea
Galaxy S5 SM-G900W8 - LTE 700/850/900/1800/1900/2100/2600 Canada
Galaxy S5 SM-G900M - LTE 700/850/1700/1900/2100/2600 USA for Vodafone 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900A - LTE 700/850/1700/1800/1900/2100/2600 USA for AT&T 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900T - LTE 700/850/900/1700/1800/1900/2100/2600 USA for T-Mobile 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900T1 - LTE 850/900/1800/1900 USA for MetroPCS 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900P - LTE 850/900/1800/1900 USA for Sprint 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900R4 - LTE 700/850/1700/1900/2100 USA for US Cellular 
Galaxy S5 SM-G900V - LTE 700/1700/2100 USA for Verizon
```

FYI: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/89990/12202

There is also the [Samsung Galaxy S5 Duos SM-G900FD, a.k.a. Samsung Galaxy S5 Duos LTE](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s5_duos-6272.php), which is pretty much like the SM-G900F but dual-SIM.